# Stop Upload to SQL database if permission is not granted

Tags: php, sql

I need to stop data being uploaded to the database when permissions are not granted. Is there a way to kill the session and only permit my script to upload data if permission has been granted.

PAGE 1:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']='studentadmin';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style >
body {background-color: rgb(255,66,69);}
h3{font-size: 250%};
h4{font-size: xx-small;}
</style>    
<title>Student Examinations 2017 </title>
<body>
<font style="font-family: Arial;";

<h4>Chichester Secondary School</h2>

<div align="center">
<h3>End of Year Examinations 2017</h1>
<i><p>Using the form below please submit examination results for the end of the academic year.</p></i> 
<i><p>This years results are represented with the new government grading system. '9-1' rather than 'A*-G' </i></p>

<form action="MySQL.php" method="POST"><br>
<b> <br> Student: </b><br>

<br> First Name <br>
<input type="text" name="fname"><br/>
Last Name <br>
<input type="text" name="lname"><br/>
<br>    

<br><b>Exam Board: <br></b><br>
<input type="radio" name = "examboard" value="AQA" checked> AQA 
<input type="radio" name = "examboard" value="EdExcel" checked> EdExcel <br><br>

<b><br>Subject Grades: </b><br> 
<br>

English<br>  
<select name="Grade">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>

   </select><br>
Maths<br> 
<select name="Grade2">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
   </select><br>
Science<br>   
<select name="Grade3">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
   </select><br>

<br> Additional Comments <br>
 <textarea name ="additionalcomments" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset">

<br>

</head>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PAGE 2:

```
    <?php 
session_start(); 
if (isset($_SESSION ['user'])) {
    echo "Student record successfully created by user: " .$_SESSION['user'];
unset($_SESSION['user']);
} else {
    echo 'You do not have permission to access this page. ';
}
?>

<?php
$DB_HOST = "localhost";
$DB_USERNAME = "admin";
$DB_PASSWORD = "chichester";
$DB_NAME = "results";

$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$examboard = $_POST["examboard"];
$grade = $_POST["Grade"]; 
$grade2 = $_POST["Grade2"];
$grade3 = $_POST["Grade3"];
$additionalcomments = $_POST["additionalcomments"];

$conn = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);

$sql = "INSERT INTO studentresults (name,lastname,examboard,additionalcomments,grade, grade2, grade3) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$examboard','$additionalcomments','$grade','$grade2','$grade3')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
}
$conn->close();

?>

<html>
<head>
<style >
body {background-color: rgb(255,66,69);}
h3{font-size: 500%};
h4{font-size: x-large;}
</style>    
<title>Results </title>
<body>
<font style="font-family: Arial;";
```

Comment: What about implementing some validation instead of kiliing session.

Answer (score 1):

When someone "doesn't have permission" this is what you do:

```
echo 'You do not have permission to access this page. ';
```

You simply *tell them* they don't have permission.  But you continue to execute the code *anyway*.  If you want the script to stop processing, something like the `exit` command would accomplish that:

```
exit('do not have permission to access this page. ');
```

---

Also of note... You're outputting a message indicating that a record was successfully inserted *before* you actually insert anything into the database.  That's... optimistic.  You should really only be indicating success to the user *if the operation is successful*.  If the operation fails in some way, your users are going to be very confused.

Comment: Entries are still being created to the database.

Comment: @ZakComber: Then the condition you're checking isn't working, likely because an assumption you've made somewhere isn't true.  What *specifically* is happening?  When you debug your code, how *specifically* is it failing?

Comment: I don't know, I am new to programming.

Comment: @ZakComber: Then I guess start with an introductory tutorial on PHP?  At the very least, in order to solve any problem in your code you're going to have to be able to *observe* the results of your code.  We can't debug this on your computer for you.  Put helpful `echo` statements throughout your code to output useful information (runtime values of variables, etc.) and look at the output on the page.  Use that to determine more specifically what's happening when the code executes.

Comment: @David your suggestion is valid, however, the reason your solution by itself did not solve the problem was that he has $_SESSION['user'] = 'studentadmin'; at the very start of his code, therefore the code will never enter the else you were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you start your code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['user']='studentadmin';
?>
```

Here you assume that `studentadmin` has logged in and you stored that as user. It is incorrect practice. Somehow you need to make sure that your admin is valid instead of assuming it.

Later you have this:

```
session_start(); 
if (isset($_SESSION ['user'])) {
    echo "Student record successfully created by user: " .$_SESSION['user'];
unset($_SESSION['user']);
} else {
    echo 'You do not have permission to access this page. ';
}
```

As David already pointed out, here, if there is no `$_SESSION['user']`, then you just echo a message and continue anyway. His suggestion of using exit is needed here, but only if you remove the part where you assign a value to `$_SESSION['user']` anyway. However, damage is already done, users are already considered to be `studentadmin`. May I suggest that you should use a different key from now on, like `$_SESSION['username']`, so old, invalid `$_SESSION['user']` values will not allow things which should not be allowed? But this will only work if you have a proper login screen where people enter their credentials, which are in turn validated and you only store `$_SESSION['username']` if the credentials were valid.